# Is there a code that cause an ereader from assuming a page-break between adjoining files

Tags: css, epub

I have a number of books that I am editing in Sigil in which the author chose not to have Chapters or other major sectioning -- consequently, the book consists of one single continuous page that, because of epub size limitations, is broken into many separate files.  But they need to be displayed on an ereader as a continuous page.  Is there a code that will cause the ereader to not issue a page-break when moving from one file to the next?  I have tried page-break-before:always and page-break-after:always -- but no success.  Does anyone know of a way join two separate files for display purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Starting on a new page for each XHTML document is a choice made by the Reading Systems. The vast majority of ePub Reading Systems (Apple iBooks, Adobe Reader Mobile) follow this rule.
There is nothing you can do about this, as long as the majority of ereaders are based on Adobe Reader Mobile, which is the only Reading System to apply the size limitations for XHTML documents.